# How do I allocate a class (using new) when that class has a nested abstract class?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and am porting over code from Java.  I have a renderer class which has a method that takes an interface as an argument.  This way the caller can define how to render its buffers.  Now I'm running into trouble when I try to 'new' the ported over class.  I get the error 'allocating an object of abstract class type'.  This is the part of my code that I think I need to do something about:

```
// Interface to the OpenGL ES renderer; consumed by GLView
struct IRenderingEngine {
virtual void initialize(int width, int height) = 0;
virtual void render() const = 0;
virtual ~IRenderingEngine() {}
};

class Renderer : public IRenderingEngine
{
public:
    ...

class IDrawGLBuffer
{
public:
    virtual ~IDrawGLBuffer() {};
    virtual void function(VBODescription vboDescription,
                          ShaderDescription shaderDescription);
};

class ShaderDescription
{
public:
    ShaderDescription(){};
    ShaderDescription(string vertexShaderText,
                      string fragmentShaderText,
                      map<string,GLint>& variableMap,
                      IDrawGLBuffer& callback,
                      int vertexDimensions);
    GLuint getProgramID() const {return shaderProgramID;};
    int getVertexDimensions() const {return vertexDimensions;};
    friend class Renderer;
private:
    string vertexShaderText;
    string fragmentShaderText;
    GLuint shaderProgramID;
    IDrawGLBuffer callback;
    int vertexDimensions;
    map<string,GLint> variableMap;
};

class VBODescription
{
public:
    VBODescription(){};
    VBODescription(string shaderName,
                   map<string, Buffer>& variableMap,
                   GLenum usage,
                   int indexTotal,
                   GLuint textureID);
    int getIndexTotal() const {return indexTotal;};
    GLuint getTextureID() const {return textureID;};
    friend class Renderer;
private:
    GLenum usage;
    map<string, Buffer> variableMap;
    string shaderName;
    int indexTotal;
    GLuint textureID;

};

    ...

};
```

Comment: Has IRenderingEngine class pure virtual functions?

Comment: Please post complete code. Also be aware that C++ nested classes are very different from Java nested classes. There is no "this" pointer from the outer class stored in the inner class.

Comment: @Joe if it's a pure abstract class it might. I've seen lots of them.

Comment: Did you try to take `IDrawGLBuffer` interface out? Or is there a specific reason why you want to keep it nested?

Comment: I don't see any abstract class here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't, and can't easily, include the interface directly in the class as you've done:

```
IDrawGLBuffer callback;
```

This allocates space for the interface only (which doesn't take any room, being abstract), and you can't know the size of any implementation (it could and probably does inherit the interface and add private members).

What you should do is pass a pointer to the implementation of the interface, and then store that:

```
Ctor(IDrawGLBuffer * pDrawImpl);
std::shared_ptr<IDrawGLBuffer> m_DrawImpl;
```

You then call methods from the interface using the pointer syntax (`a->b(c)`).

Since it's not possible for the compiler to know how big an implementation of an interface will be later, using pointers to reference the memory (which is somewhat known) becomes very important.

I used a `shared_ptr` here to help automatically release the impl, although you may need a `CComPtr` or if your class is a bit odd, `boost::intrusive_ptr`. When working with interfaces, smart pointers are your friend (more than regularly).

Comment: Prefer using `std::unique_ptr` to `std::shared_ptr` and you will not accidentally end up *sharing* the "m_DrawImpl" pointee between several instances of the class.

Comment: I was hoping to use a virtual method to avoid the use of pointers.  Ah oh well.  I'll give this a try, it makes sense.

Comment: Virtual methods and pointers are meant to be used together, one enables the other. Virtual methods, in very short, make the type of the pointer not matter; precisely so you can do things like interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

The inner class "class IDrawGLBuffer" is irrelevant because an instance of it won't be allocated when you create a new instance of class Renderer (unless Renderer contains an instance of IDrawGLBuffer by value and you've omitted it from your summary).

The error `'allocating an object of abstract class type'` will be given if you create a new instance of Renderer but Renderer does not contain overrides for all pure virtual functions in its base class (IRenderingEngine). Usually your compiler will tell you which are missing.

Edit: from the updated code, it looks like Renderer needs to contain a definition of `void render() and void initialise(int,int)`, but it does not